# FrameworkElementFactory information

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, frameworkelementfactory

I've been looking everywhere for proper documentation on the internet about the **`FrameworkElementFactory`** class, but I cannot seem to find proper tutorials or useful information on it.

Can someone that knows a bit more about this subject give me more information on it please? Here is what i've found so far from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456714/data-bound-datagrid-with-custom-column-headers) question: (Thanks to Bob)

Bind the ItemsSource to `myDataGrid`:

```
Binding dataGridItemsSourceBinding = new Binding("MyItemsSourceName");
myDataGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, datagridItemsSourceBinding);
```

---

---

Create a DataGridTemplateColumn

```
 DataGridTemplateColumn templatecolumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn() {
      Header = "myColumnName", // Add the name of your column here
 };
```

---

---

Create the Data Template for when you are displaying the value in the DataCell for the DataGrid Column

```
 // Displaying Template for when you display the DataCell in the DataGridColumn
 // Create a Data Template for when you are displaying a DataGridColumn
 DataTemplate textBlockTemplate = new DataTemplate();
 // Create a Framework Element for the DataGridColumn type (In this case, a TextBlock)
 FrameworkElementFactory textBlockElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
 // Create a Binding to the value being displayed in the DataGridColumn
 Binding textBlockBinding = new Binding("myPropertyName");
 // Assign the Binding to the Text Property of the TextBlock
 textBlockElement.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, textBlockBinding);
 // Set the DataGridColumn to stretch to fit the text
 textBlockElement.SetValue(TextBlock.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch);
 // Add the TextBlock element to the Visual Tree of the Data Template
 textBlockTemplate.VisualTree = textBlockElement;
 // Add the Data Template to the DataGridColumn Cell Template
 templatecolumn.CellTemplate = textBlockTemplate;
```

---

---

Create the Data Template for when you are editing the value in the DataCell for the DataGrid Column

```
 // Editing Template for when you edit the DataCell in the DataGridColumn
 // Create a Data Template for when you are displaying a DataGridColumn
 DataTemplate textBoxTemplate = new DataTemplate();
 // Create a Framework Element for the DataGrid Column type (In this case, TextBox so the user can type)
 FrameworkElementFactory textBoxElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
 // Create a Binding to the value being edited in the DataGridColumn
 Binding textBoxBinding = new Binding("myPropertyName");
 // Assign the Binding to the Text Property of the TextBox
 textBoxElement.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, textBoxBinding);
 // Set the DataGridColumn to stretch to fit the text
 textBlockElement.SetValue(TextBlock.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch);
 // Add the TextBox element to the Visual Tree of the Data Template
 textBoxTemplate.VisualTree = textBoxElement;
 // Add the Data Template to the DataGridColumn Cell Editing Template
 templatecolumn.CellEditingTemplate = textBoxTemplate;
```

---

---

Add the completed DataGridColumn to your DataGrid

```
 // Add the completed DataGridColumn to your DataGrid
 myDataGrid.Columns.Add(templateColumn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this thread: [Purpose of using FrameworkElementFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091853/purpose-of-using-frameworkelementfactory)

As for now Microsoft does not recommend using the `FrameworkElementFactory`